# How to visualise eml files?

Tags: linux, x11, email, utilities

I have many email archived in `eml` format. The problem is that I can't view them without installing an email client and importing eml files, which is tedious and not what i want.

Ideally, I would like to find something like a pdf viewer that opens when you click on the file.

I currently use `munpack -t <file.eml>` that extracts attachments and text in separate files. It kinda works but it's tedious.

As a reference, when I am on a Windows desktop, I use quicklook which opens the eml file like any other text or pdf file.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird opens .eml files, just like that, no need for importing them.

Comment: Fresh Thunderbird install opens an empty composer windows Write:(no subject) and does not show email content. It does not display eml file content.

Comment: it does for me, something's strange with your setup, maybe? Does it work if you open Thunderbird, go "File"->"Open"->"Saved Message…"?

Comment: Turns out it is my file explorer Caja that is not able to launch it properly. Shame since it is quite a good window manager for my other uses.

Comment: probably not an issue with the file explorer, just with how the file associations are set

Answer (score 1):

So does KMail from KDE.

KDE file manager used to generate thumbnails for EML files in the past - not sure if this feature is still there.

Comment: I'm kind of in the same boat as GnuSam above except with KMail. When I do a `kmail x.eml`, it opens a new compose window for me ...

Answer (score 0):

mhonarc (a Perl program) can convert EML files to HTML and pipe the output to a web browser; examples:

```
mhonarc -single email.eml | w3m -T text/html
mhonarc -single email.eml | lynx -stdin
```